# jQuery finding class name value from class array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, class, find

I am trying to find the exact value of a class name containing the text `iconGroup` and I am able to get an array of class names using:

```
var chosenIconClassArray = $('.selectedGroupIcon').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
console.log(chosenIconClassArray);
$.each(chosenIconClassArray, function(index, item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

This gives a console output of:

```
["createAGroupIconList", "inlinelist", "ram", "left", "iconGroup20", "selectedGroupIcon"]

createAGroupIconList
inlinelist
ram
left
iconGroup20
selectedGroupIcon
```

I have tried something along the lines of this to find which `iconGroup` it is, but it didn't work:

```
if (item ^= 'iconGroup') {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

The goal is to be able to tell that the class array contains the value `iconGroup20` (or any number such as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc) which I can then add to another element to update it's icon.

How can I go about searching that array and then find which `iconGroup` class is in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something that finds classes on an item that match the format 'iconGroup##'? If so, try something like this:

```
function getIconGroup(class_array) {
  var iconGroup = false;
  $.each(class_array, function(index, item) {
    if item.match(/^iconGroup[0-9]+$/) {
      iconGroup = item;
    }
  });
  return iconGroup;
}
```

**Updated to act as a function so you can use `getIconGroup(ChosenIconClassArray)`.**

Comment: Thanks Corey, how can I prevent the item from being overwritten with `null` when the class array contains classes after the `iconGroup##` in the `each` loop?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a `String.indexOf` method. It'll return the index of the string you give it, or -1 if the string wasn't found.

The following piece of code should give you the class you're hoping for.

```
var chosenIconClassArray = $('.selectedGroupIcon').attr('class').split(/\s+/),
    foundClass;
$.each(chosenIconClassArray, function(index, item) {
    if (item.indexOf('iconGroup') > -1) {
        foundClass = item;
    }
});
```

The variable `foundClass` should contain the full class.

Comment: Thanks James, I had tried out `indexOf` but was unsure if it would be cross-browser.  Also, this function (had) an illegal break statement so it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry, try replacing `break;` with `return false;`. That should help. String.indexOf has huge browser support, so use it with confidence